# Given the my code is open source and I'm running on a server, and I accept nearly-raw code, what's the worst that can happen to me?

Tags: python, security, code-injection

I'm looking at several cases where it would be far, far, far easier to accept nearly-raw code. So,

1. What's the worst you can do with an expression if you can't lambda, and how?
2. What's the worst you can do with executed code if you can't use import and how?
   (can't use X == string is scanned for X)

Also, B is unecessary if someone can think of such an expr that given d = {key:value,...}:
expr.format(key) == d[key]

Without changing the way the format looks.

Comment: string is scanned for "import"... but did you consider exec("i"+"mport smtplib") ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The worst you can do with an expression is on the order of

```
__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')
```

if the server process is running as `root`. Otherwise, you can fill up memory and crash the process with

```
2**2**1024
```

or bring the server to a grinding halt by executing a [shell fork bomb](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Fork_bomb#Examples):

```
__import__('os').system(':(){ :|:& };:')
```

or execute a temporary (but destructive enough) fork bomb in Python itself:

```
[__import__('os').fork() for i in xrange(2**64) for x in range(i)]
```

Scanning for `__import__` won't help, since there's an infinite number of ways to get to it, including

```
eval(''.join(['__', 'im', 'po', 'rt', '__']))
getattr(__builtins__, '__imp' + 'ort__')
getattr(globals()['__built' 'ins__'], '__imp' + 'ort__')
```

Note that the `eval` and `exec` functions can also be used to create any of the above in an indirect way. If you want safe expression evaluation on a server, use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: Drawing from the experience on other fora / discussion sites I would like to advice visitor who don't have a full understanding of command line environment: **don't try to run the example command!!** [It will wipe out your entire root filesystem]

Comment: Hmm.. For execs, you could kill it after one second; You could run it in a sandbox where nor file, nor open, nor __import__, nor import are defined (I mean, have a value of none). Oh, more or less ditto for eval.

Comment: @GLycan: "you could kill it after one second".  Funny.  It will be way, waaay to late.  The `rm -rf /` takes one scheduling cycle (a few ms) to do enough damage that your system will no longer run properly.

Comment: I ment that as a deterent to fork bombs and the like. rn -rf / requires imports to be blocked

Answer (score 3):

Arbitrary Python code?

- Opening, reading, writing, creating files on the partition. Including filling up all the disk space.
- Infinite loops that put load on the CPU.
- Allocating all the memory.
- Doing things that are in pure Python modules without importing them by copy/pasting their code into the expression (messing with built in Python internals and probably finding a way to access files, execute them or import modules).
  ...

Comment: See above, except allocating memory. I could make a length limit; but someone elegent enough could get around that. Please give me some examples.

Answer (score 2):

No amount of whitelisting or blacklisting is going to keep people from getting to dangerous parts of Python.  You mention running in a sandbox where "open" is not defined, for example.  But I can do this to get it:

```
real_open = getattr(os, "open")
```

and if you say I won't have `os`, then I can do:

```
real_open = getattr(sys.modules['os'], "open")
```

or

```
real_open = random.__builtins__['open']
```

etc, etc, etc.  Everything is connected, and the real power is in there somewhere.  Bad guys will find it.

Comment: Yes, but if you *only* have builins and the actual stuff your code is supposed to be changing (e.g. game varibles), then how would you get to sys, os, or random?

Comment: Are you really comfortable betting that you are smarter than everyone who might want to exploit your system?

Comment: No matter how narrow an interface you think you are providing, there is going to be a way to get down to the `__builtins__` module, and it will have dangerous stuff.  People have experimented with "sandboxed" Python before, and it's *extremely* difficult.