# Python - efficient way to create 20 variables?

Tags: python, variables, exec, creation

I need to create 20 variables in Python. That variables are all needed, they should initially be empty strings and the empty strings will later be replaced with other strings. I cann not create the variables as needed when they are needed because I also have some if/else statements that need to check whether the variables are still empty or already equal to other strings.

Instead of writing

```
variable_a = ''
variable_b = ''
....
```

I thought at something like

```
list = ['a', 'b']
for item in list:
    exec("'variable_'+item+' = '''")
```

This code does not lead to an error, but still is does not do what I would expect - the variables are not created with the names "variable_1" and so on.

Where is my mistake?

Thanks, Woodpicker

Comment: Why variables, and not a 20-element list, or a dictionary?

Comment: Listen to Marcelo Cantos, use a dict/list.

Comment: for something like variable_1, variable 2.. write list = range(1,20) instead. And I agree with Marcelo, why don't you use a list or dictionary?

Comment: you would have to say `exec("variable_"+item+" = ''")`, but this is a terrible idea, so do what larsmans suggested

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Where is my mistake?

There are possibly three mistakes. The first is that `'variable_' + 'a'` obviously isn't equal to `'variable_1'`. The second is the quoting in the argument to `exec`. Do

```
for x in list:
    exec("variable_%s = ''" % x)
```

to get `variable_a` etc.

The third mistake is that you're not using a `list` or `dict` for this. Just do

```
variable = dict((x, '') for x in list)
```

then get the contents of "variable" `a` with `variable['a']`. Don't fight the language. Use it.

Comment: I'm conflicted about whether showing him how he could do what he tried is a good idea or a bad idea...

Comment: 4th mistake is using `list` as a variable name

Comment: For using `exec` there is a special circle of hell reserved for you.

Comment: @Jakob, you mean where demons do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609664/given-the-my-code-is-open-source-and-im-running-on-a-server-and-i-accept-nearly/6609766#6609766) to you?

Comment: I never got that far because I learnt about the dangers of eval before they happened.

Comment: OK, mistake 1 is of course a typo - it should have been 'variable_a' instead of _1... Secone mistake - OK I will not use exec... ;-)
Third mistake: OK, I will try a dictionary, but I am not entirely sure about how to use it... Could you give me a hint how I can use a dictionary I have defined in a class in a function of this class, and pass the dictionary that has been modified in this function back to the parent level for later use in other functions?

Comment: @Woodpicker: since a `dict` is a Python object like any other, you can pass it around as an argument or return value.

Comment: OK, sorry, stupid question. Got it... Thanks for all input. Using a dict now and will never again dare to ask for 'exec' - although I have not understood why it is so bad...

Comment: @Woodpicker: that's another question entirely, but among its evils is that programs using it are much harder to reason about than ones using a `dict`; so why go the hard way if the language has an easy solution for your problem? (There are also issues of security, tools not understanding program parts encoded as string literals, and so on.)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same question as others (of not using a list or hash), but if you need , you can try this:

```
for i in xrange(1,20):
    locals()['variable_%s' %i] = ''
```

Im assuming you would just need this in the local scope. Refer to [the manual](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) for more information on locals

Comment: The manual says this "**Note:** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."

Comment: This kind of answer is bad in at least two way: they are incorrect (it does not work) and they promote bad designs

Comment: @Simon, I dint see the note about it should not be changed in the manual, so accept the fact that its bad, but it does work. see  http://pastebin.com/2aB3FZtP

Comment: @rajasuar, just because it happens to work in one implementation of python does not mean you should use it. Your code may break on other implementations.

Comment: @rajasuar then I hope you only use toplevel in python, because once you start using this method inside functions, it breaks: http://ideone.com/QjyF1

Comment: @Simon and if instead of locals we use globals? this works in your example, and nothing seems to be bad according to documentation... what do you think?

Comment: @fransua it works with globals, but you don't want to do this because you may end up with very strange non-local effect, very hard to debug. As Rick Osborne said: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live."

Answer (score -1):

never used it, but something like this may work:

```
liste = ['a', 'b']
for item in liste:
    locals()[item] = ''
```

Comment: you can't modify the return value of `locals()` http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: I do not get exactly why... the example is working...
sorry for bad answer :)