# creating a dictionary named as variable

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I am using pyodbc to query database and retrieve some data (obviously).
What I would like is to create new dictionaries namd according to values returned from query.
For example I have a table with 1000 items, and one of collumns in that table is a INT number which is in range 1-51.
I want to do a rundown through my table, and create dictionaries named : **bought_I**, **sold_I**, **created_I**, etc... where I stands for INT number.
I hope I am clear enough :)
I know I could premade those dicts, but range will not always be 1-51, and it's nicer and cleaner to do it programmatically than to hardcode it.

Comment: Why not use another layer of dicts, or, even better, a combination of dicts and lists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - efficient way to create 20 variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678547/python-efficient-way-to-create-20-variables) and see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided

Answer (score 9):

Don't.

Create a dictionary `bought`, and give it keys based on your number:

```
bought = {}
for number in column_x:
    bought[number] = "whatever object you need here"
```

Same for `sold`, `created` etc.

Or just one big `dict`:

```
mydict = {"bought": {}, "sold": {}, "created": {}}
for number in column_x:
    for key in mydict:
        mydict[key][number] = "whatever"
```

Comment: Or a list, if it's always going to be numbers 1-x.

Comment: It came to me that using a dict with dicts as values could be usefull.
Hmm, I will give it a thought.

Comment: Also, how do I perform something like :

mydict[key][number] = mydict.get([key][number],0) + VARIABLE
?